# Scrape texts from multiple websites and save separately in text files

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I am a beginner in python, have been using it for my master thesis to conduct textual analysis in gaming industry. I have been trying to scrape reviews from several gaming critic sites.

I used a list of URLs in the code to scrape the reviews and have been successful. Unfortunately, i could not write each reviews in a separate file. as i write the files, either i receive only the review from the last URL in the list to all the files, or all of the reviews in all of the files after changing the indent. following here is my code. could you kindly suggest what's wrong in here?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls= ['http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2018/05/08/ao-international-tennis-review/#/slide/1',
'http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2018/03/27/atelier-lydie-and-suelle-review/#/slide/1',
'http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2018/03/15/attack-on-titan-2-review-from-a-different-perspective-ps4/#/slide/1']  

for url in urls:
    r=requests.get(url).text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
for i in range(len(urls)):
    file=open('filename%i.txt' %i, 'w')    
    for article_body in soup.find_all('p'):
        body=article_body.text
        file.write(body)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need one for loop. If I understand correctly, you only want to iterate through `urls` and store an individual file for each.

Therefore, I would suggest removing the second `for` statement. You do though then need to modify the `for url in urls` to get a unique index for the current url you can use for `i` and you can use `enumerate` for that.

Your single `for` statement would become:

```
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
```

I've not tested this myself but this is what I believe should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @adambro i changed the code accordingly but did not receive any output

Comment: for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    r=requests.get(url).text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    for article_body in soup.find_all('p'):
        body=article_body.text
        print(body)

Comment: i removed the filename code, fixed it and ran it. It works perfectly now!! thanks a lot @adambro & stackoverflow, this has been a life saver. All the best!!

Comment: for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    r=requests.get(url).text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    file=open('filename%i.txt' %i, 'w')    
    for article_body in soup.find_all('p'):
        body=article_body.text
        #print(body)
        file.write(body)
    file.close()

Answer (score 0):

I totally believe you are a beginner in python. I post the right one before explaining it.

```
for i,url in enumerate(urls):
    r = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    file = open('filename{}.txt'.format(i), 'w')
    for article_body in soup.find_all('p'):
        body = article_body.text
        file.write(body)
    file.close()
```

The reason why `i receive only the review from the last URL in the list to all the files`

one variable for one value , so after for-loop finished you will get the last result(the third one). The result of first and second result will be override

```
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
```